# Couchbase - connections between nodes

Tags: connection, nodes, couchbase

Could anyone explain what type of connections are between the nodes?
Are they anyhow encrypted? I cannot find anything in the official documentation.

Update: 
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/security/security-comm-encryption.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version you are running and the deployment topology you have chosen with services, Couchbase Server has a number of connections between nodes. You can find the list here for the ports we use for internal communication between nodes under "node to node";
http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/install/install-ports.html

Couchbase Server does not encrypt communication between nodes today. You can use other solutions like IPSec to do that. Couchbase Server does encrypt data access, web console and cluster to cluster communication with XDCR.